# Postgres extremely slow after upgrade from Version 10 to 11

Tags: postgresql, performance, statistics, postgresql-10, postgresql-11, postgresql-performance

Related to this:[PostgreSQL extremely slow after upgrade from 9.3 to 9.4](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/191335/postgresql-extremely-slow-after-upgrade-from-9-3-to-9-4)
but trying to understand better...

My queries was slow after upgrading to Postgres Version 11.5 from 10.7
I first ran `ANALYZE` on the DB but still was slow!
so I can `VACUUM ANALYZE` on the DB, and was still slow...

as a last resort, I am running `VACUUM FULL ANALYZE` on a table by table basis using psycopg2 with autocommit on (http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/connection.html#connection.autocommit) to be able to run it in psycopg2

one table is taking hours to do ...
while I wait, I can't help but wonder what went wrong.
The reduction of the query performance was mainly from UPSERT.

Comment: "*one table is taking hours to do ...*" - maybe it's waiting for a lock? Did you check `pg_stat_activity` to see if your `vacuum` command is active? Do you have connections that are `idle in transaction`? Those will prevent vacuum from doing its job

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The culprit was even with `VACUUM FULL ANALYZE`, query planner  was still not using indexes in many cases.

Solved by forcing `SET enable_seqscan = OFF;`, after few autovacuums, it re-adjusted.

Answer (score 4):

The output of pg_upgrade includes this:

```
...

Upgrade Complete
----------------
Optimizer statistics are not transferred by pg_upgrade so,
once you start the new server, consider running:
    ./analyze_new_cluster.sh

...
```

We found horrible performance straight after the upgrade until we ran this, lesson learned to read the output :)